# Buffered level of music showing in seekbar

Tags: android, progress-bar, media-player, android-seekbar

[image]

Hi there. As you can see i want to show buffered level of media that stream to user in android music player.
The solution i imagine for this issue is that:
Should i create a seekbar and a progressbar with transparent background and overlap progressbar to seek bar, whereas progreesbar showing buffered level of music.

but im not sure about this strategy. is anyone to help me for best way to reaching the goal at this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all should implements `OnBufferingUpdateListener` to activity then set onBufferingUpdate ike this:

```
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int percent) {
    /** Method which updates the SeekBar secondary progress by current song loading from URL position*/
    seekBarProgress.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
}
```

Comment: it should be seekBar.setSecondaryProgress( seekBar.getMax() * percentage/100) to make it work. Make sure you have already converted your percentage to decimal first so that when you divide it by 100, you get a decimal value not 0.

Answer (score 1):

Just because setting percentage directly doesn't work. Here is the code that worked for me.

```
mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int percent) {
            double per = percent * 1.00;
            per = (per / 100);
            double f = (seekBar.getMax() * 1.00);
            f = f * per;
            if (percent < binder.seekBar.getMax()) {
                seekBar.setSecondaryProgress((int) f);
            }
        }
    });
```

These int to double conversions are necessary because int division by 100 will give you 0 if result was to be 0.12 or 0.xx.